# How to print variable name in Cobol

Tags: c, variables, cobol

I am trying to pass to a C function the variable names from a cobol program.

```
   01 Message.
         03 varA         PIC X(32).
         03 varB         PIC X(32).
```

Consider the fact that this function will be used in many programs and the structure of variable `Message` will be different everytime , how can i pass to the C function the names of the variables?
I allready consider making another group data item to contain the variable names, but this is not a good solution for me.

I am using Microfocus Server Express v5.1 on AIX.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to do. Do you want to pass both a variable name and a variable to a C function ???. You might be able to achieve it with a Copy replacing

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question. It's kinda vague for me. Nevertheless, here's a link that might work for you. It's about passing variables between COBOL and C.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ceea400/cee14272.htm

Comment: How might _the structure of [the] variable `Message` [...] be different everytime_? Different lengths? Different number of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > how can i pass to the C function the names of the variables?

It is not possible to pass a variable name, directly, with `CALL USING`; at least, not one that would be better than a group data item.

What I did here is to create a JSON-like object using a `STRING` statement with a `REPLACE` statement to pass a name/value pair. I chose this method because there are many open source libraries that may be called from `C` to decode `JSON` objects. It also very flexible with regard to text lengths and the number of variables to be passed.

[Ed. Changed code to place all `STRING` statement data items in the `REPLACE` statement. Changed some names to reflect "name/value" pairings. Removed string length code to nested program.]

```
   program-id. call-c.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 msg.
    2 varA pic x(32) value "Message 1".
    2 varB pic x(32) value "Message 2".
   1 lengths binary.
    2 len-1 pic 9(4).
    2 len-2 pic 9(4).
   replace
       ==name-1== by =="varA"==
           ==value-1== by ==varA(1:len-1)==
       ==name-2== by =="varB"==
           ==value-2== by ==varB(1:len-2)==
       ==newline== by ==x"0a"==
       .
   1 json-string pic x(256).
   procedure division.
   begin.
       compute len-1 = function length (varA)
       call "rtrim-len" using varA len-1

       compute len-2 = function length (varB)
       call "rtrim-len" using varB len-2

       string
           "{" newline
               quote name-1 quote ": "
                 quote value-1 quote "," newline
               quote name-2 quote ": "
                 quote value-2 quote newline
           "}" x"00"
           delimited size into json-string
       call "c_prog" using
           by reference json-string
       stop run
       .

   program-id. rtrim-len.
   data division.
   linkage section.
   1 str pic x(256).
   1 str-len binary pic 9(4).
   procedure division using str str-len.
   begin.
       perform varying str-len from str-len by -1
       until str-len < 1 or str (str-len:1) not = space
           continue
       end-perform
       exit program
       .
   end program rtrim-len.
   end program call-c.
```

A COBOL program to substitute for a called `C` program.

```
   program-id. "c_prog".
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 json-string-count binary pic 9(4).
   1 json-string-pos binary pic 9(4).
   1 json-text-count binary pic 9(4).
   1 json-text pic x(64).
   linkage section.
   1 json-string pic x(256).
   procedure division using json-string.
   begin.
       move 0 to json-string-count
       inspect json-string tallying
           json-string-count for characters before x"00"
       move 1 to json-string-pos
       perform until json-string-pos > json-string-count
           unstring json-string delimited x"0a" or x"00"
               into json-text count json-text-count
               pointer json-string-pos
           display json-text (1:json-text-count)
       end-perform
       exit program
       .
   end program "c_prog".
```

Output:

```
{
"varA": "Message 1",
"varB": "Message 2"
}
```

If a `TRIM` function is available, the length calculations, data items, and nested program are not needed and the `REPLACE` statement becomes,

```
   replace
       ==name-1== by =="varA"==
           ==value-1== by ==trim(varA)==
       ==name-2== by =="varB"==
           ==value-2== by ==trim(varB)==
       ==newline== by ==x"0a"==
       .
```

Comment: And if he uses the GnuCOBOL "from version control" he can directly use the IBM extension `GENERATE JSON json-string FROM msg` and have the json generated in a single line :-)

Comment: @rick smith Thank you very much for your code and explanation, it was usefull for me to solve my problem and dig deeper.

Comment: @SimonSobisch that is my problem, I am using microfocus cobol server expres v5.1 which doesn't include the `GENERATE JSON` statement. I am trying to build a function (I prefer to use C) that does the same thing as `Generate json`